# Vuex state empty after reload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Inside a mutation I'm changing my `state` like:

```
try {
  const response = await axios.put('http://localhost:3000/api/mobile/v3/expense/vouchers/form_refresh', sendForm, {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer ###'
    }
  });

  var obj = cloneDeep(response.data);
  var temp = cloneDeep(response.data.line_items_attributes.nested_form)

  temp = Object.keys(temp).map(key => {
    return {
      ...temp[key]
    }
  });

  obj.line_items_attributes.nested_form = cloneDeep(temp);

  state.form = cloneDeep(obj);
  console.log(state.form);
} catch (error) {
  ...
}
```

So the `state` shall hold an array with an object as the entry. Checking the `state` also shows the same. And it's displayed on the view.
When now reloading everything remains inside the `state` except of the object inside the array. It just shows an empty array inside the store:

```
line_items_attributes:
  attribute: "line_items_attributes"
  label: "Positionen"
  model_class: "expense_line_item"
  nested_form: []              // <---- Object is gone
```

Nested_form is a hahsmap delivered by the backend. I just turn it to an array. line_items_attribute is a property of the object stored in the state.
EDIT: But it's also not working without the transformation. The assigned state there just doesn't get preserved.

store.js

```
const store = createStore({
    strict: false,
    plugins: [createPersistedState()],
    modules: {
        expense,
        invoice
    }
});
```

Calling the action/mutation like:

```
const updateOuter = (event, refreshable, propertyName) => {
   store.dispatch('expense/updateOuterValue', ({
      refresh: refreshable,
      propertyName: propertyName,
      value: event.target.checked ? 1 : 0
   }))
};
```

EDIT:

When changing a different value after calling the mutation the `nested_form` object is being preserved after the reload.

It seems to work if I call the mutation twice... Any idea how this could be?

Comment: You shouldn't do async operations inside mutations, use actions instead.

Comment: @e200 Could that be a reason?

Comment: How does your vuexpersistatedstate setup look? And clarify more about the part with the line_items_attribues, is that a nested object or your state or what? Give more info on how it all is setup.

Comment: To answer the question regarding mutation, no if it all works it's not the reason, it's however a common best practise, probably your other setup.

Comment: @Dejan.S persistedState is just included as a plugin in my state file. It works for all other states, so that's not the problem.

I'll do an edit.

Comment: Vuex isn't Local Storage it should gone after reload. Use local storage or cache instead

Comment: @FatimaMazhit That's what vuexPersistedState is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the execution of axios inside the mutation. There **must** be no asynchronous calls inside a Vuex mutation. As suggested by @e200

> You shouldn't do async operations inside mutations, use actions instead.

So it's more than just a *best practice*, rather a must do.
Explianed here: [mutations must be synchronous](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-must-be-synchronous)